# Is there an analysis speed or memory usage advantage to using HDF5 for large array storage (instead of flat binary files)?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, pytables, h5py

I am processing large 3D arrays, which I often need to slice in various ways to do a variety of data analysis. A typical "cube" can be ~100GB (and will likely get larger in the future)

It seems that the typical recommended file format for large datasets in python is to use HDF5 (either h5py or pytables). My question is: is there any speed or memory usage benefit to using HDF5 to store and analyze these cubes over storing them in simple flat binary files? Is HDF5 more appropriate for tabular data, as opposed to large arrays like what I am working with? I see that HDF5 can provide nice compression, but I am more interested in processing speed and dealing with memory overflow.

I frequently want to analyze only one large subset of the cube. One drawback of both pytables and h5py is it seems is that when I take a slice of the array, I always get a numpy array back, using up memory. However, if I slice a numpy memmap of a flat binary file, I can get a view, which keeps the data on disk. So, it seems that I can more easily analyze specific sectors of my data without overrunning my memory.

I have explored both pytables and h5py, and haven't seen the benefit of either so far for my purpose.

Comment: HDF is a "chunked" file format. On average, it will give you much faster reads for an arbitrary slice of your dataset. A memmap will have a fast best-case, but a very, very slow worst-case. `h5py` is better suited to datasets like yours than `pytables`.  Also, `h5py` does _not_ return an in-memory numpy array.  Instead it returns something that behaves like one, but isn't loaded into memory (similar to a `memmapped` array).  I'm writing up a more complete answer (may not finish it), but hopefully this comment helps a bit in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks.

I agree that h5py returns a dataset that is similar to a memmap. But, if you do a slice of the h5py dataset, it returns a numpy array, which I believe (?) means the data has been put into memory needlessly. A memmamp returns a view to the original memmap if possible. In other words: `type(cube)` gives `h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset`. While `type(cube[0:1,:,:])` gives `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: However, your point about the average read time is interesting.

Comment: If you have an I/O bottleneck then in many cases compression can actually improve read/write performance (especially using fast compression libraries such as BLOSC and LZO), since it reduces the I/O bandwidth required at the cost of some extra CPU cycles. You might want to look at [this page](https://pytables.github.io/usersguide/optimization.html), which has a lot of information about optimizing read-write performance using PyTables HDF5 files.

Comment: "if I slice a numpy memmap of a flat binary file, I can get a view, which keeps the data on disk" - that may be true, but if you actually want to *do* anything with the values in that array then sooner or later you will have to load them into RAM. A memory-mapped array just provides some encapsulation so that you don't have to think about exactly when the data gets read or whether it will exceed your system memory capacity. In some circumstances the native caching behaviour of memmaped arrays can be [very suboptimal indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21096605/1461210).

Comment: I agree that it has to go into memory at some point. However, views are still useful. For example, I often want to do analysis on a specific sector of the cube too large to fit in memory. A view of a slice of the data is a nice book-keeping device. I can pass the view of the cube to any code designed to run on the entire cube. Otherwise, all of my code, which is designed to run piece-wise over the data, will need to be able to optionally run over specific ranges. A view would let me reuse the same code designed to run over the entire code, save coding time, and be less bug-prone.

Comment: My view question is probably worth a separate post, since this has become a general overview of why HDF5 is a good way to store data. The new post is at http://stackoverflow.com/q/27803331/1361752

Answer (score 192, accepted):

### HDF5 Advantages: Organization, flexibility, interoperability

Some of the main advantages of HDF5 are its hierarchical structure (similar to folders/files), optional arbitrary metadata stored with each item, and its flexibility (e.g. compression).  This organizational structure and metadata storage may sound trivial, but it's very useful in practice.

Another advantage of HDF is that the datasets can be either fixed-size *or* flexibly sized. Therefore, it's easy to append data to a large dataset without having to create an entire new copy.

Additionally, HDF5 is a standardized format with libraries available for almost any language, so sharing your on-disk data between, say Matlab, Fortran, R, C, and Python is very easy with HDF. (To be fair, it's not too hard with a big binary array, too, as long as you're aware of the C vs. F ordering and know the shape, dtype, etc of the stored array.)

### HDF advantages for a large array: Faster I/O of an arbitrary slice

**Just as the TL/DR:** For an ~8GB 3D array, reading a "full" slice along any axis took ~20 seconds with a chunked HDF5 dataset, and 0.3 seconds (best-case) to *over three hours* (worst case) for a memmapped array of the same data.

Beyond the things listed above, there's another big advantage to a "chunked"* on-disk data format such as HDF5: Reading an arbitrary slice (emphasis on arbitrary) will typically be much faster, as the on-disk data is more contiguous on average.

`*`(HDF5 doesn't have to be a chunked data format. It supports chunking, but doesn't require it. In fact, the default for creating a dataset in `h5py` is not to chunk, if I recall correctly.)

Basically, your best case disk-read speed and your worst case disk read speed for a given slice of your dataset will be fairly close with a chunked HDF dataset (assuming you chose a reasonable chunk size or let a library choose one for you).  With a simple binary array, the best-case is faster, but the worst-case is *much* worse.

One caveat, if you have an SSD, you likely won't notice a huge difference in read/write speed.  With a regular hard drive, though, sequential reads are much, much faster than random reads.  (i.e. A regular hard drive has long `seek` time.) HDF still has an advantage on an SSD, but it's more due its other features (e.g. metadata, organization, etc) than due to raw speed.

---

First off, to clear up confusion, accessing an `h5py` dataset returns an object that behaves fairly similarly to a numpy array, but does not load the data into memory until it's sliced.  (Similar to memmap, but not identical.)  Have a look at the [`h5py` introduction](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#dataset) for more information.

Slicing the dataset will load a subset of the data into memory, but presumably you want to do something with it, at which point you'll need it in memory anyway.

If you do want to do out-of-core computations, you can fairly easily for tabular data with `pandas` or `pytables`. It is possible with `h5py` (nicer for big N-D arrays), but you need to drop down to a touch lower level and handle the iteration yourself.

However, the future of numpy-like out-of-core computations is Blaze. [Have a look at it](http://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) if you really want to take that route.

---

### The "unchunked" case

First off, consider a  3D C-ordered array written to disk (I'll simulate it by calling `arr.ravel()` and printing the result, to make things more visible):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.arange(4*6*6).reshape(4,6,6)

In [3]: arr
Out[3]:
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
        [  6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11],
        [ 12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17],
        [ 18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23],
        [ 24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
        [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35]],

       [[ 36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41],
        [ 42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47],
        [ 48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53],
        [ 54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59],
        [ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65],
        [ 66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71]],

       [[ 72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77],
        [ 78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83],
        [ 84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89],
        [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95],
        [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101],
        [102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107]],

       [[108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113],
        [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119],
        [120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125],
        [126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131],
        [132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137],
        [138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143]]])
```

The values would be stored on-disk sequentially as shown on line 4 below. (Let's ignore filesystem details and fragmentation for the moment.)

```
In [4]: arr.ravel(order='C')
Out[4]:
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
        52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,
        65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
        78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
        91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103,
       104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
       117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129,
       130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143])
```

In the best case scenario, let's take a slice along the first axis.  Notice that these are just the first 36 values of the array.  This will be a *very* fast read! (one seek, one read)

```
In [5]: arr[0,:,:]
Out[5]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

Similarly, the next slice along the first axis will just be the next 36 values. To read a complete slice along this axis, we only need one `seek` operation. If all we're going to be reading is various slices along this axis, then this is the perfect file structure.

However, let's consider the worst-case scenario: A slice along the last axis.

```
In [6]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[6]:
array([[  0,   6,  12,  18,  24,  30],
       [ 36,  42,  48,  54,  60,  66],
       [ 72,  78,  84,  90,  96, 102],
       [108, 114, 120, 126, 132, 138]])
```

To read this slice in, we need 36 seeks and 36 reads, as all of the values are separated on disk. None of them are adjacent!

This may seem pretty minor, but as we get to larger and larger arrays, the number and size of the `seek` operations grows rapidly. For a large-ish (~10Gb) 3D array stored in this way and read in via `memmap`, reading a full slice along the "worst" axis can easily take tens of minutes, even with modern hardware. At the same time, a slice along the best axis can take less than a second.  For simplicity, I'm only showing "full" slices along a single axis, but the exact same thing happens with arbitrary slices of any subset of the data.

Incidentally there are several file formats that take advantage of this and basically store three copies of *huge* 3D arrays on disk: one in C-order, one in F-order, and one in the intermediate between the two.  (An example of this is Geoprobe's D3D format, though I'm not sure it's documented anywhere.)  Who cares if the final file size is 4TB, storage is cheap!  The crazy thing about that is that because the main use case is extracting a single sub-slice in each direction, the reads you want to make are very, very fast. It works very well!

---

### The simple "chunked" case

Let's say we store 2x2x2 "chunks" of the 3D array as contiguous blocks on disk.  In other words, something like:

```
nx, ny, nz = arr.shape
slices = []
for i in range(0, nx, 2):
    for j in range(0, ny, 2):
        for k in range(0, nz, 2):
            slices.append((slice(i, i+2), slice(j, j+2), slice(k, k+2)))

chunked = np.hstack([arr[chunk].ravel() for chunk in slices])
```

So the data on disk would look like `chunked`:

```
array([  0,   1,   6,   7,  36,  37,  42,  43,   2,   3,   8,   9,  38,
        39,  44,  45,   4,   5,  10,  11,  40,  41,  46,  47,  12,  13,
        18,  19,  48,  49,  54,  55,  14,  15,  20,  21,  50,  51,  56,
        57,  16,  17,  22,  23,  52,  53,  58,  59,  24,  25,  30,  31,
        60,  61,  66,  67,  26,  27,  32,  33,  62,  63,  68,  69,  28,
        29,  34,  35,  64,  65,  70,  71,  72,  73,  78,  79, 108, 109,
       114, 115,  74,  75,  80,  81, 110, 111, 116, 117,  76,  77,  82,
        83, 112, 113, 118, 119,  84,  85,  90,  91, 120, 121, 126, 127,
        86,  87,  92,  93, 122, 123, 128, 129,  88,  89,  94,  95, 124,
       125, 130, 131,  96,  97, 102, 103, 132, 133, 138, 139,  98,  99,
       104, 105, 134, 135, 140, 141, 100, 101, 106, 107, 136, 137, 142, 143])
```

And just to show that they're 2x2x2 blocks of `arr`, notice that these are the first 8 values of `chunked`:

```
In [9]: arr[:2, :2, :2]
Out[9]:
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[36, 37],
        [42, 43]]])
```

To read in any slice along an axis, we'd read in either 6 or 9 contiguous chunks (twice as much data as we need) and then only keep the portion we wanted. That's a worst-case maximum of 9 seeks vs a maximum of 36 seeks for the non-chunked version. (But the best case is still 6 seeks vs 1 for the memmapped array.) Because sequential reads are very fast compared to seeks, this significantly reduces the amount of time it takes to read an arbitrary subset into memory. Once again, this effect becomes larger with larger arrays.

HDF5 takes this a few steps farther.  The chunks don't have to be stored contiguously, and they're indexed by a B-Tree.  Furthermore, they don't have to be the same size on disk, so compression can be applied to each chunk.

---

### Chunked arrays with `h5py`

By default, `h5py` doesn't created chunked HDF files on disk (I think `pytables` does, by contrast).  If you specify `chunks=True` when creating the dataset, however, you'll get a chunked array on disk.

As a quick, minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = np.random.random((100, 100, 100))

with h5py.File('test.hdf', 'w') as outfile:
    dset = outfile.create_dataset('a_descriptive_name', data=data, chunks=True)
    dset.attrs['some key'] = 'Did you want some metadata?'
```

Note that `chunks=True` tells `h5py` to automatically pick a chunk size for us.  If you know more about your most common use-case, you can optimize the chunk size/shape by specifying a shape tuple (e.g. `(2,2,2)` in the simple example above).  This allows you to make reads along a particular axis more efficient or optimize for reads/writes of a certain size.

---

### I/O Performance comparison

Just to emphasize the point, let's compare reading in slices from a chunked HDF5 dataset and a large (~8GB), Fortran-ordered 3D array containing the same exact data.

I've [cleared all OS caches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87909/4100) between each run, so we're seeing the "cold" performance.

For each file type, we'll test reading in a "full" x-slice along the first axis and a "full" z-slize along the last axis.  For the Fortran-ordered memmapped array, the "x" slice is the worst case, and the "z" slice is the best case.

The code used is [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/joferkington/77edf001b8c699a14e06) (including creating the `hdf` file).  I can't easily share the data used here, but you could simulate it by an array of zeros of the same shape (`621, 4991, 2600)` and type `np.uint8`.

The `chunked_hdf.py` looks like this:

```
import sys
import h5py

def main():
    data = read()

    if sys.argv[1] == 'x':
        x_slice(data)
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'z':
        z_slice(data)

def read():
    f = h5py.File('/tmp/test.hdf5', 'r')
    return f['seismic_volume']

def z_slice(data):
    return data[:,:,0]

def x_slice(data):
    return data[0,:,:]

main()
```

`memmapped_array.py` is similar, but has a touch more complexity to ensure the slices are actually loaded into memory (by default, another `memmapped` array would be returned, which wouldn't be an apples-to-apples comparison).

```
import numpy as np
import sys

def main():
    data = read()

    if sys.argv[1] == 'x':
        x_slice(data)
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'z':
        z_slice(data)

def read():
    big_binary_filename = '/data/nankai/data/Volumes/kumdep01_flipY.3dv.vol'
    shape = 621, 4991, 2600
    header_len = 3072

    data = np.memmap(filename=big_binary_filename, mode='r', offset=header_len,
                     order='F', shape=shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    return data

def z_slice(data):
    dat = np.empty(data.shape[:2], dtype=data.dtype)
    dat[:] = data[:,:,0]
    return dat

def x_slice(data):
    dat = np.empty(data.shape[1:], dtype=data.dtype)
    dat[:] = data[0,:,:]
    return dat

main()
```

Let's have a look at the HDF performance first:

```
jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ sudo ./clear_cache.sh

jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ time python chunked_hdf.py z
python chunked_hdf.py z  0.64s user 0.28s system 3% cpu 23.800 total

jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ sudo ./clear_cache.sh

jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ time python chunked_hdf.py x
python chunked_hdf.py x  0.12s user 0.30s system 1% cpu 21.856 total
```

A "full" x-slice and a "full" z-slice take about the same amount of time (~20sec).  Considering this is an 8GB array, that's not too bad.  Most of the time

And if we compare this to the memmapped array times (it's Fortran-ordered: A "z-slice" is the best case and an "x-slice" is the worst case.):

```
jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ sudo ./clear_cache.sh

jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ time python memmapped_array.py z
python memmapped_array.py z  0.07s user 0.04s system 28% cpu 0.385 total

jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ sudo ./clear_cache.sh

jofer at cornbread in ~ 
$ time python memmapped_array.py x
python memmapped_array.py x  2.46s user 37.24s system 0% cpu 3:35:26.85 total
```

Yes, you read that right. 0.3 seconds for one slice direction and ~3.5 *hours* for the other.

The time to slice in the "x" direction is *far* longer than the amount of time it would take to load the entire 8GB array into memory and select the slice we wanted! (Again, this is a Fortran-ordered array.  The opposite x/z slice timing would be the case for a C-ordered array.)

However, if we're always wanting to take a slice along the best-case direction, the big binary array on disk is very good. (~0.3 sec!)

With a memmapped array, you're stuck with this I/O discrepancy (or perhaps anisotropy is a better term).  However, with a chunked HDF dataset, you can choose the chunksize such that access is either equal or is optimized for a particular use-case.  It gives you a lot more flexibility.

### In summary

Hopefully that helps clear up one part of your question, at any rate.  HDF5 has many other advantages over "raw" memmaps, but I don't have room to expand on all of them here.  Compression can speed some things up (the data I work with doesn't benefit much from compression, so I rarely use it), and OS-level caching often plays more nicely with HDF5 files than with "raw" memmaps.  Beyond that, HDF5 is a really fantastic container format. It gives you a lot of flexibility in managing your data, and can be used from more or less any programming language.

Overall, try it and see if it works well for your use case.  I think you might be surprised.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to add that you can customize your chunking layout to your typical data access pattern. If you access pattern has a fairly predictable stencil size, you can typically choose your chunking such as to achieve near optimal speed at all times.

Comment: Great answer!

One thing that isn't mentioned about chunking is the effect of the chunk cache. Each open dataset has its own chunk cache, the default size of which is 1 MB, that can be adjusted using H5Pset_chunk_cache() in C. It's generally useful to consider how many chunks can be kept in memory when thinking about your access patterns. If your cache can hold, say, 8 chunks and your dataset is 10 chunks in the direction of the scan, you will thrash a lot and performance will be terrible.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use HDF5 files and `numpy.memmap`, but a couple new tools have made my life a lot easier... and faster: [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/index.html) by PyData and [`zarr`](https://zarr.readthedocs.io).

xarray upgrades to "HDF5":

1. Labeled axes (like a Pandas DataFrame)
2. Compression (like HDF5)
3. Customized chunk size and shape (like HDF5)
4. Almost any storage backend, including HDF5 and `zarr` (a more modern HDF5)
5. Optimize chunking and caching of data streamed over the internet (S3 buckets, NAS, cloud storage)

I don't have a speed comparison, yet, but I'm working on it for a vector-search backend for `knowt` (a RAG LLM that needs to semantically search (do dot products) on all of Wikipedia fast).

Comment: I'm going to keep the original comment as the selected answer, since it answers the original question more specifically. However, this is a useful alternative answer for people looking into this space. I myself have started using xarray, and agree its great. I think a lot of the details given in Joe's comment above apply to xarray as well.

I've been mostly using xarray with the netcdf data format, but have been interested in checking out zarr.

Comment: @Caleb yea the accepted answer is much more informative; and since I made this post I've reverted to memmap because I ran into some challenges getting xarray to work as fast as memmap, and the labeled axes turned out to be less convenient on legacy archives after forgetting the schema/names and xarray API.