# How to skip lines and read first n characters to make processing a large file more efficiently?

Tags: python

I have a large file wile hundreds of millions of lines.

Each line has thousands of characters.

For every four lines, I want to read in line1, and perform a condition test.

Then based on this test, I will decide whether to read in the following line2. (I can just read them in without doing anything, but it makes the process too slow by wasting resources.)

If line1 condition is True, I want to read in line2, but only first n characters, also to save time because this line is very long.

Then I will definitely skip line 3 and 4.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to implement this?

Basically, I want to make processing this large file significantly faster.
Right now, it is very slow by doing the following:

```
while(1):
     line = file.readline()
     if not line:
       break
     else:
       if line == something:
         lst.append(file.readline()[:10])
         file.readline()
         file.readline()
```

Comment: In order to skip a line, you must first read the line, because lines in text files are terminated by line breaks `"\n"`, and unless you find a line break, you wouldn't know that a new line begins. I do not think you can make your code substantially faster.

Comment: I do not know if it is faster, so I will not give this as a direct answer, but it is possible to read in the content of a whole file at once. Then this in your memory and maybe speed up. You could try to use some mutli processing library to get a real speed up at the end

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html Here is the documentation for multiprocessing in python. basically run a thread for every four lines and do the check in parallel, this can give you a speed up based on the cores available

Comment: Reading the whole file is almost impossible for my memory...

Comment: @Kev1n91 You cannot parallelize this task, because getting the next 4 lines  requires that the previous 4 lines have been already read.

Comment: You can read the file in chunks, as big as you can afford. You have to be careful with lines that start in one chunk and end in the next chunk.

Comment: But in order to use multiprocessing, you still need to read in, say 400 lines and split it into 10 cores. It will not reduce any time because you still read in all lines.

Comment: @DYZ But you can parallelise it over each 4 lines, so that line 0,4,8,12,14 and so on are all done in parallel. Thus, I would assume it still would make a speed up - cause you can check them and process them in parallel even if they are in chunks. For 400 lines you can process it on 4 - 8 threads I guess in parallel and thus have this 400 lines processed like it would be 100 or 50 lines.

Comment: @Kev1n91 The bottleneck is not in processing, the bottleneck is in getting data from the file (which is 6 orders of magnitude slower than any CPU-bound task).

Comment: Try running it with a counter, like `n=0, x = [], while n<1,000,000:, line = file.readline, if n%4==0 and (perform your condition):, x.append(line)`. Mind you it might take some time.

Comment: @Kev1n91 I think multiprocessing will only benefit me significantly if processing line2 is complicated. In my case, I think reading lines is the bottleneck here.

Comment: do your know your amount of lines beforehand?

Comment: I can 'wc -l' it in the command-line and pipe it

Comment: Wait, maybe I can sed the file in the command line to get first two lines for every four lines and pipe it in, although I still have to read in the whole line2, which is the longest.

Comment: There is a moudle called linecache: https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html , This seems to be the state of the art method to access single lines of files. As you mentioned before you can not read the file in to the whole memory, maybe it is able with this module - however if not you could try to make some preprocessing to split up the files in smaller chunks and then give it to the this module, but the so created work may take away the benefit from the caching

Comment: Isn't HDF5 files useful under such circumstances? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710245/is-there-an-analysis-speed-or-memory-usage-advantage-to-using-hdf5-for-large-arr