# Dynamic advanced indexing of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement a function that can compute basic math operations on large array (that won't whole fit in RAM). Therefor I wanted to create a function that will process given operation block by block over selected axis. Main thought of this function is like this:

```
def process_operation(inputs, output, operation):
    shape = inputs[0].shape
    for index in range(shape[axis]):
        output[index,:] = inputs[0][index:] + inputs[1][index:]
```

but I want to be able to change the axis by that the blocks should be sliced/indexed.

is it possible to do indexing some sort of dynamic way, not using the ':' syntactic sugar?

I found some help [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) but so far wasn't much helpful:

thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) for on-disk/out-of-RAM arrays?

Comment: Yes, but after some googling, I found more useful use of h5py [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710245/is-there-an-analysis-speed-or-memory-usage-advantage-to-using-hdf5-for-large-arr). But when I perform basic math operations like np.add() on them it loads whole "datasets" to memory. When I try to pass another dataset as output parameter -> I get TypeError, that I'm not passing Arraylike object. I have bunch of arrays and I need to process some Basic math operations and some convolutions -> and pass results between compute blocks (performing the operations)

Comment: @NilsWerner so far Ill stick with your suggestion to use numpy.memmap. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you could achieve what you want using python's builtin [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) type.

Under the hood, `:`-expressions used inside square brackets are transformed into instances of `slice`, but you can also use a `slice` to begin with. To iterate over different axes of your input you can use a tuple of `slice`s of the correct length.

This might look something like:

```py
def process_operation(inputs, output, axis=0):
    shape = inputs[0].shape
    for index in range(shape[axis]):
        my_slice = (slice(None),) * axis + (index,)
        output[my_slice] = inputs[0][my_slice] + inputs[1][my_slice]
```

I believe this should work with h5py datasets or memory-mapped arrays without any modifications.

### Background on `slice` and `__getitem__`

`slice` works in conjunction with the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) to evaluate the `x[key]` syntax. `x[key]` is evaluated in two steps:

1. If `key` contains any expressions such as `:`, `i:j` or `i:j:k` then these are de-sugared into `slice` instances.
2. `key` is passed to the `__getitem__` method of the object `x`. This method is responsible for returning the correct value of `x[key]`

For the example the expressions:

```py
x[2]
y[:, ::2]
```

are equivalent to:

```py
x.__getitem__(2)
y.__getitem__((slice(None), slice(None, None, 2)))
```

You can explore how values are converted to slices using a class like the following:

```py
class Sliceable:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(key)

x = Sliceable()
x[::2] # prints "slice(None, None, 2)"
```