# Speed analysis/prediction for hdf5 (h5py or pytables) vs numpy memmep (vs other) for retrieving 100s of rows. 30 million rows total, each of 512 ints

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py, pytables

I have 30 million rows of data. Each contains an int array of size 512. Each int can have values from 0 to 50,500.

I'll need to retrieve about 100 rows simultaneously in one instance. I am wondering which data store will give the fastest retrieval for this.

It seems that the best datastores for this type of situation are hdf5 and numpy memmaps.

I am wondering if there is some sort of analysis or prediction for what may be faster for my situation.

I saw this
[Is there an analysis speed or memory usage advantage to using HDF5 for large array storage (instead of flat binary files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710245/is-there-an-analysis-speed-or-memory-usage-advantage-to-using-hdf5-for-large-arr)

But the situation is quite different from mine.

Comment: Is the data here helpful? https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d

Comment: Do you want to access a slice of rows or some random rows from the dataset? Is the data compressible (not completely random)? How do you write the file (column or row-wise)? eg. h5py: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/4045774 But there are a lot faster compression algorithms available than lzf....

Comment: I want to access random rows; the list of rows could be [32, 1, 48390202, 34543, 3244, etc]. The data represents nodes on a graph, so its not random, but I don't think it's compressible. For now we have written it row-wise, but we don't really care if it's row or column wite.