# Is there aother reason to use pickle instead of excel to store pandas dataframes rather than IO?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I am creating a small dataset of pandas datasets. I think it's better than trying to improve it into a SQLite.

I am choosing the format of the datasets. For my initial load, it reduced the size of the file in 45% compared than using Excel. But because it's small, it's 45% of 585KB. When comapred to CSV, it's the just a little smaller.

I think that Excel enables me to have some flexebility with the data and I am willing to pay the IO price. Am I missing some advantage of Pickle?

Comment: probably not. At least not for this use case.

Comment: If certain elements in your dataframe are true python objects like dictionaries, lists, etc...maybe using pickle for data serialization is a better choice since on-read, it preserves its type. It really depends on the use case, how often it's read and how quickly it must be read, etc...

Comment: Unless you are also using the data in Excel app, you are really not getting any benefits from the overhead an excel format needs. I suggest you look into binary formats like the widely used `parquet`, or `feather` (which is faster with pandas but not universally readable)... I haven't used HDF5 but according to this answer it has many benefits https://stackoverflow.com/a/27713489/6692898

Answer (score 0):

I just re-ran my performance tests. `msgpack`, `feather` and `parquet` have changed interfaces or been removed so no longer work.

My use case was more around which serialisation format to use to cache data frames in a Redis cache.  There is no clear winner

1. using pickle works but you will get deprecation warnings from pandas and does maintain backward compatibility.  It's a python only serialisation format
2. using pyarrow gives more portability,  can be used in python, java, ....  However it does not maintain backward compatibility across versions [ARROW-7961](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7961)
3. to compress or not again is a decision based on space / time trade off

I continue to use `pyarrow` and am happy with it.  However my code will automatically switch to `pickle` if it spots a transitory backward compatibility issue.

```
import sys, pickle, zlib, warnings, io
import pyarrow as pa

t = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,1,3), freq='min'))
uh = [random.randint(0,50) for e in t]
out = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":t, "user_holding":uh})

class foocls:
    def pyarrow(out): return pa.serialize(out).to_buffer().to_pybytes()
#     def msgpack(out): return out.to_msgpack()
    def pickle(out): return pickle.dumps(out)
#     def feather(out): return out.to_feather(path=io.BytesIO())
#     def parquet(out): return out.to_parquet(io.BytesIO())

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
for c in foocls.__dict__.values():
    sbreak = True
    try:
        c(out)
        print(c.__name__, "before serialization", sys.getsizeof(out))
        print(c.__name__, sys.getsizeof(c(out)))
        %timeit -n 50 c(out)
        print(c.__name__, "zlib", sys.getsizeof(zlib.compress(c(out))))
        %timeit -n 50 zlib.compress(c(out))
    except TypeError as e:
        if "not callable" in str(e): sbreak = False
        else: raise
    except (ValueError) as e: print(c.__name__, "ERROR", e)
    finally: 
        if sbreak: print("=+=" * 30)        
warnings.filterwarnings("default")
```

**output**

```
pyarrow before serialization 46256
pyarrow 51901
630 µs ± 59.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
pyarrow zlib 20041
2.72 ms ± 53.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
=+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+=
pickle before serialization 46256
pickle 47166
96.7 µs ± 5.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
pickle zlib 19276
1.95 ms ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 50 loops each)
=+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+==+=
```